# Fastest xml reader for large xml files with java

Tags: java, xml, jsp, sax

I have an xml file with 100 000 fragments with 6 fields in every fragment.I want to search in that xml for different strings at different times.

What is the best xml reader for java?

Answer (score 3):

OK, let's say you've got a million elements of size 50 characters each, say 50Mb of raw XML. In DOM that may well occupy 500Mb of memory, with a more compact representation such as Saxon's TinyTree it might be 250Mb. That's not impossibly big by today's standards.

If you're doing many searches of the same document, then the key factor is search speed rather than parsing speed. You don't want to be doing SAX parsing as some people have suggested because that would mean parsing the document every time you do a search.

The next question, I think, is what kind of search you are doing. You suggest you are basically looking for strings in the content, but it's not clear to what extent these are sensitive to the structure. Let's suppose you are searching using XPath or XQuery. I would suggest three possible implementations:

a) use an in-memory XQuery processor such as Saxon. Parse the document into Saxon's internal tree representation, making sure you allocate enough memory. Then search it as often as you like using XQuery expressions. If you use the Home Edition of Saxon, the search will typically be a sequential search with no indexing support.

b) use an XML database such as MarkLogic or eXist. Initial processing of the document to load the database will take a bit longer, but it won't tie up so much memory, and you can make queries faster by defining indexes.

c) consider use of Lux (http://luxdb.org) which is something of a hybrid: it uses the Saxon XQuery processor on top of Lucene, which is a free text database. It seems specifically designed for the kind of scenario you are describing. I haven't used it myself.

Comment: Thanks a lot fr ur knkwledge.i will try xquery processor and database.in the meantime.iwill tellu wht I m going to do is that I have 10-15 no of links on first page.all are having names from name1-5,when we click on them.it shud go tonext page with the name  and it shud in search in xml at that time and give me the desired fragments in next jsp page in tabular format.tell me fr this scenario.whether STAX or woodstox can be an option???

Answer (score 1):

Are you loading the XML document into memory once and then searching it many times? In that case, it's not so much the speed of parsing that should be the concern, but rather the speed of searching. But if you are parsing the document once for every search, then it's fast parsing you need. The other factors are the nature of your searches, and the way in which you want to present the results.

You ask what is the "best" xml reader in the body of your question, but in the title you ask for the "fastest". It's not always true that the best choice is the fastest. because parsing is a mature technology, different parsing approaches might only differ by a few microseconds in performance. Would you be prepared to have four times as much development effort in return for 5% faster performance?

Comment: Which will be the best method.ifwe want to search in xml data again and again.shud we load xml In memory in that case...??

Comment: I think you should look seriously at loading the data into an XML database.

Comment: I developed the pages first with XML DOM.it worked for first two times it ran.but then from next time.eclipse gave me memory issue in server..shud I go for some other parser in this case or I shud go with DOM only and load data in my database......?????

Answer (score 0):

The solution to handling very big XML files is to use a SAX parser. With DOM parsing, any library would really fail with very big XML file. Well, failing is relative to the amount of memory you have and how efficient is the DOM parser.

But anyway, handling large XML files requires SAX parser. Consider SAX as something which just throw elements out the XML file. It is an even based sequential parser. Even based because you are thrown with elements such as start element, end element. You have to know which element you are interested in getting and handle them properly.

I would advise you to play with this simple example to understand SAX, 
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/

Comment: Using a pull parser is another option, as efficient as a SAX parser.

Comment: Can we read comapre a string to a specific node text with SAX parser and retrieve a result

Comment: @Codo, thanks, I never knew there was something called Pull Parser

Comment: @user2839745, yes, we can, with SAX, you just need to know how to get hold of the interested element when the SAX parser is throwing it

Comment: SAX is "event" based. I had to read the sentence twice before realizing what you were trying to say :)